# Is there a way to change the values of multiple items in a functional component object? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a CV application and I want the user to be able to input different things such as the title, company, date, etc. But I want them all inside the same object. When I try doing this:

Each time I change the value of an input, the object changes as well, but the old one doesn't get printed - it just replaces it for the new one. For example, when I'm writing the value of `"title"` - it changes correctly, but when I start changing the `"company"` - it changes to the company one like this: `"company": value` instead of `"Title": value, "company": value`

I know that class components perform the job correctly, but I was wondering if I could do the same for functional components without creating extra states.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import '../styles/style.css'

const Experience = (props) => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
    const [input, setInput] = useState({title: "", company: ""})

    const togglePopup = () => {
        setToggle(!toggle);
    }
    return(
        <ul>
            { JSON.stringify(input) }
            <button onClick={togglePopup}>Work Experience</button>
            {toggle && <form>
                <div>
                    <label>Job Title</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input  onChange={ e => {setInput({ title: e.target.value }) }}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Company</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input onChange={ e => {setInput({ company: e.target.value }) }}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Date Worked (MM/YYYY - MM/YYYY)</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Location (e.g. Los Angeles, CA)</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Description</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input />
                </div>
                <button>Save</button>
                <button onClick={togglePopup}>Cancel</button>
            </form>}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default Experience
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
setInput({ ...input, company: e.target.value })
```

When you `setInput({company: e.target.value});` it will replace the old object with your new object which is `{ company: e.target.value }`. You can create new object with new changes and keep the previous unchanged state using the spread operator (`...`).

---

On the side note.

```
<input onChange={ e => {setInput({ title: e.target.value }) }}/>
```

Should be

```
<input
  value={input.title}
  onChange={ e => {setInput({ title: e.target.value }) }}
/>
```

Since you already handle onChange. So it should be controlled component. Using `onChange` without `value` will get some complain from react for mixing uncontrolled component with controlled component.